# jQuery animate delay issues with self -queued looping of steps

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate

I have a `timeline` definition which lists selectors and a list of delays and animations to apply to that object.  You can specify that the steps for a particular object be looped.

Here is the function that's used to queue the animations:

```
function animateWithQueue(e, obj) {
    if ($.queue(e[0]).length == 0) {
        e.queue(function doNext(next) {
            $.each(obj.steps, function(i, step) {
                e.delay(step.pause).animate(step.anim, step.options);
            });
            if (obj.loop) {
                e.queue(doNext);
            }
            next();
        });
    }
}​
```

Here is the `timeline` information

```
var timeline = {
    '.square': {
        loop: true,
        steps: [
            { pause: 800, anim: { right: '+=200' }, options: { duration: 400} },
            { pause: 1000, anim: { right: '-=200' }, options: { duration: 400} }
        ]
    },
    '.circle': {
        loop: true,
        steps: [
            { pause: 1200, anim: { top: '+=200' }, options: { duration: 400} },
            { pause: 1200, anim: { top: '-=200' }, options: { duration: 400} }
        ]
    }
};
```

And here is the function that puts the `timeline` into the above animate function:

```
$.each(timeline, function(selector, obj) {
    animateWithQueue($(selector), obj);
});
```

Here is a full example. http://jsfiddle.net/sprintstar/Tdads/

This code appears to work fine, the animations loop and the stop button can be clicked to stop the animations, clear the queues etc.  However the issue we're facing can be triggered by hitting stop and start over and over (say 10 times).  Then notice that the delays are not functioning correctly any more, and the shapes move about much faster.

Why is this, and how can it be fixed?

Comment: Is there any way you can trigger the bug programmatically? It would help the debug process.

Comment: I could, but the manual stop/starting mirrors how our application works, and I think its easier to see the effect of the delays not working when you can see it moving before, and then after clicking the stop/start buttons.

Comment: added multiple start-stop-start
http://jsfiddle.net/tjdA3/
reproduced :)

Comment: That really screws the animation up. lol  Probably the same issue though. If there is only one queue per element, what is going on here?

Comment: something wrong with the delays i think

Comment: Okay, this is just a tip, but for something like this I REALLY recommend for you to check out http://www.greensock.com/v12/. TimelineLite is a javascript animation timeline (play, repeat, rewind, seek, and way more) that uses TweenLite Javascript animation engine to animate whatever you want. It's really easy to understand if you look at the examples and also usable with jQuery selectors. Oh, and it's WAY faster!

Comment: Yeah, for sure next time I will use a different library to do this. Thanks for the recommendation. I was looking at http://createjs.com/#!/TweenJS also.  However this stuff is heavily baked into our app now, I just need to fix the delay issue.

Answer (score 1):

Something is not working quite right with `delay`...

As a work around, I've replaced it with [`doTimeout`](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-dotimeout-plugin/) in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tjdA3/10/), so the following:

```
  e.delay(step.pause).animate(step.anim, step.options);
```

Becomes:

```
    var timerName = e[0].className + $.now();
    timeouts.push(timerName);
    e.queue(function(next) {
      e.doTimeout(timerName, step.pause, function() {
          this.animate(step.anim, step.options);
          next();
        });
    });
```

`timeouts` is an array of unique timeout ids - each of which is cleared when the stop button is pressed.

As I've said, more of a workaround than a fix, as you'll also need to reset the position of the elements on stop too. (notice I've removed the += and -= from the top/right definitions)

Answer (score 0):

looking at your stop handler i woudl suspect the .stop() to be miss placed.
i would target it on .circle and .square instead of the holding div.

Had an issue once with animate, as the element was moving faster and faster and faster and cam to the conclusion that animate was stacking up on himself.

api.jquery.com/clearQueue/ and http://api.jquery.com/stop/ might be usefull

Comment: The circle and square are both divs in the playground, so it does target them, not the holding div.

Comment: i saw that this morning, sorry for the miss-reading but i'm still suspecting the stop() and/or clearQueue() to be source of your problem. Have you tried the clearQueue(true).

Comment: I have updated my fiddler test, but it makes no difference. :(